# Placing two select elements vertically one above the other, with centrally aligned horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want two dropdown menus, one below other, and then I need more stuff aligned below that as well (say a button below these two).

[image]

I thought to combine all of these in a div.

My DIV is classed as .filter-search
and both drop downs are classed as .drop

CSS code below.

```css
.filter-search {
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 40px
}

.drop {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 12px 360px 12px 8px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

My problem currently is that even though both drop downs (1 and 2) have the same text, even then the size of the dropdowns differs by a small fraction. i.e. they aren't aligned left and right.

I can make them same by setting the width as 50%, but I am trying to understand why it isn't working by itself (if all the CSS attributes of both select dropdowns are the same).

Also, I am wondering if I really need the outer div in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without debugging your page it is difficult to say exactly what the problem is.

I have created a JSFiddle with an example, where i think it works like you wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/zag8hsL3/1/

The important part is the

```css
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center
```

on the `.selects` wrapper div.

Let me know if this isn't exactly what you wanted, and we can change it...